# If $\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{NUM}{DEN}$ does $Y(s) = NUM$ and $U(s) = DEN$

Tags: functions, fractions

In a course I am currently taking, my professor performed the following steps in a derivation for the reachable canonical form of a transfer function.

Given $$H(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=\frac{b_1s^2+b_2s+b_3}{s^3+a_1s^2+a_2s+a_3}$$

$$H(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=\frac{b_1s^{-1}+b_2s^{-2}+b_3s^{-3}}{1+a_1s^{-1}+a_2s^{-2}+a_3s^{-3}}\frac{X(s)}{X(s)}$$

All good so far. But then my professor did this:

$$Y(s)=(b_1s^{-1}+b_2s^{-2}+b_3s^{-3})X(s)$$
$$U(s)=(1+a_1s^{-1}+a_2s^{-2}+a_3s^{-3})X(s)$$

I am highly suspicious that this is a legal operation, but I can't think of an easy counter example. Is this step ok?

Comment: Is $X(s)$ specified? What is true is that there is some $X(s)$ for which the last two equations hold.

Comment: No. X(s) is the Laplace Transform of a state variable x(t) whose values in both the time domain and Laplace domain are generic.

Comment: It is introduced into the derivation to allow the transfer function H to be represented as a signal flow graph. I posted here because I figured this was a math question rather than a control systems (the class where this comes from) question.